# Assigning Texts and Calculation with Unity GUI buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, uibutton, calc

[image]In my code, I created a button that will the display the texts and formulas, but for some reason, I can't seem to figure out how to assign the calculation to another button.

I have two buttons, one to just assign the texts, then another button to make the calculation.  How can I assign the first button to display text and then have it assign the calculation to my second button?  I hope that make sense.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class inputFields : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject inputField1;
    public GameObject inputField2;

    public Button calcButton;

    public GameObject textDisplayTitleFormulas;
    public GameObject textDisplayFormulas;
    public GameObject textDisplayAnswer;

    public void HydrostaticPressure()
    {
        textDisplayTitleFormulas.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Hydrostatic Pressure";
        textDisplayFormulas.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Mud Weight ppg X 0.052 X TVD";

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
       {
           theMudWeight = inputField1.GetComponent<Text>().text;
           theTVD = inputField2.GetComponent<Text>().text;               
           float A = Convert.ToInt32(theMudWeight);
           float B = Convert.ToInt32(theTVD);
           float HP = A + B; 
           textDisplayAnswer.GetComponent<Text>().text = HP.ToString("N2") + " psi";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do what you did for the first button, but different? I'm not sure what your actual issue is.

Comment: How is the HydrostaticPressure function being called?  And, why are you triggering on "space" instead of using a button OnClick?

A suggestion: remove "GameObject" from the three "public GameObject textDisplay..." and replace with "Text" like this "public Text textDisplay...".  It will clean up your code and remove necessity for the GetComponent call.

Comment: I have just added the jpg image to demonstrate my app.  Hope that make more sense now.

Comment: Does pressing "CALC" call inputFields.HydrostaticPressure?

Comment: Yes, the CALC is a separate button for the calculation.  If you look at the image, I have another button for kill mud weight, ect.  I wanted each button to assign a different calculation depending on the buttons selection.

Comment: I know it's inefficient, but I'm not really a coder.  Just a 3D modeler / animator.

Comment: Understood.  Let's start with the basics, does the "CALC" button work?

Comment: Doesn't look like it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203056/discussion-between-topher-and-coder).

Comment: for the record, what he wanted to do: each of the buttons in the leftmost column does different calculations, they're pickers for what calculation is supposed to happen. and then the CALC button is supposed to do the actual math depending on which calculation was "selected" in the leftmost column.

Comment: @shcode so did you solve it? They that it stands now it is not clear and OP should either update or close the question...

Comment: Yeah.  It was solved in the chat discussion.  I basically have to rewrite to code based on Topher recommendation.